Add RowVersion column to a very large table
We need to add rowversion column to a very large table. We are on SQL 2022 and came across this post where Paul White mentioned about trace flag  - 4085 - How can I add a rowversion column to a large table with minimal downtime.
Is there any information if that trace flag is officially supported?
Thank you.

Whether a trace flag is supported or not depends on whether it is documented on the list below, your tf does not appear on the list, thus if support is required I think you should check with Microsoft support.
Although as it is a one time change couldn’t you complete the column addition & then run dbcc checkdb ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#trace-flags
”All documented trace flags and those recommended by Microsoft Support are fully supported in a production environment when used as directed.”
